# How to call a Function on load of Div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How to call a function on load of Div tag?

**First function:**

```
{ 
var name=$(link).attr('value')+"_con";
$("#content").append("<div id='name'  style='width:100%; height:100%'><div>");
initialize(name);//It will create a map inside Div content
$("#"+name).show();
}
```

In other function I call the Div to show:

**Second function:**

```
{
 $("#"+name).show();//It displays only the Div content..How to show Div content with that initilize(name) function
}
```

Comment: can you clarify your objectives a little better? Do you just want to append a map on the div you are dynamically creating?

Comment: yes...I am creating map dynamically inside the dynamic tabs...

Answer (score 1):

you post your variable as a string and not as a js variable.

```
$("#content").append("<div id='"+name+"'  style='width:100%; height:100%'><div>");
```

and than

```
$("#"+name).live('load', function () {
//do stuff
})
```

put all under document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZSAR/

Html:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
//var name=$(link).attr('value')+"_con";
  var name="something"; //Needed to hardcode this for example.
$("#content").append("<div id='"+name + "'  style='width:100%; height:100%'><div>");
initialize(name);//It will create a map inside Div content
$("#"+name).show();
});

function initialize(id){
    $("#" + id).html("<div>My Map </div>");
}
```

Comment: yes correct..but If i call $("#name").show from some other function It will display only the div canvas only...it will not call the function initialize(name);....please help me..